# Is it possible to download image from website via Selenium (Python) in case is generated dynamically from server?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, dynamically-generated

I found out in Web Inspector tool image on one site (domain is just for example)
*https://somesite.com/asd/photo.pl?num=10* which is not part of website but is probably generated dynamically from server.
I would like to ask if is possible to download it via selenium in python.
I tried this but it does not works. I think it is not possible by this way due to server site like I meantioned.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import urllib.request
import shutil
import time
import requests

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://somesite.com/")

img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/img')
img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
response = requests.get(img_url)

with open("saved_image.jpg", "wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: maybe you should show real URL - so we could see how it generates image. Maybe it needs simple method.

Comment: what means `does not works`? Did you get error? Show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). OR maybe you get some strange text in file - maybe it keep image as `base64` and you can encode it.

Comment: they may authenticate the user when you make the request.  As is, you are sending the request without any credentials.